# WPF - XAML to make DataGridTextColumnsElements align to centre

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Is there a way to globally align the text in DataGridTextColumns to the middle or center?

The xaml to do this per DataGrid is

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
  </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

However I dont want to copy and paste this code for every DataGrid, I like to do this in the app.xaml file.

I am looking for something like (But does not work)

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle}">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put styles is in a resource dictionary, referenced in App.xaml.

```
xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=WPFToolkit"

<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridColumnHeader}"  >
 <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                 Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

and Use it in your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a User control, which encapsulate your customized grid and reuse it wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a global style for all `DataGridTextColumn`s probably is not possible, because `DataGridTextColumn` is not a `FrameworkElement`, and `Style.TargetType` allows only types derived from `FrameworkElement`.

Therefore, one workaround could be to apply a formatting to **all** `DataGridCell`s like this:

```
<Application x:Class="yourprojectname.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="yourstartupuri.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```